# How do I make a perfect RoF autofire macro (sleep issue) AHK

Tags: autohotkey

Lets say I want to make a macro that clicks exactly every 82 ms.
I understand the first sleep is the latency between clicks, however lets set it to 82.
But then the latency after Lmclickup should be the latency it takes between the clicks.
I put it on 1 so I'd have around 83 ms latency, but in reality it stutters occasionally like if I would put it at 100 (the lmbutton up sleep) It'd burst fire.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
#SingleInstance Force
Process, Priority,,High
SetMouseDelay -1

~insert::Suspend

~RButton & ~LButton::
    Loop {

        Send {LButton down}
        Sleep, 82
        Send {LButton up}       
        if (GetKeyState("LButton", "P") = 0)
            break
        sleep, 1
    }
return
```

Comment: How are you testing the exact latency?

Comment: Have you tried to adapt the example in the [Sleep docs](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Sleep.htm#ShorterSleep)?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend increasing the sleep.

1ms is significantly less time than it actually takes for a human to click up and click down, your game (or whatever you are sending these clicks to) is probably not designed to handle input so quickly.

Try 20ms.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Autohotkey documentation for sleep](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Sleep.htm), the Sleep command is not exact in its timing:

> Due to the granularity of the OS's time-keeping system, Delay is typically rounded up to the nearest multiple of 10 or 15.6 milliseconds (depending on the type of hardware and drivers installed). For example, a delay between 1 and 10 (inclusive) is equivalent to 10 or 15.6 on most Windows 2000/XP systems. To achieve a shorter delay, see [Examples](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Sleep.htm#ShorterSleep).
>
> The actual delay time might wind up being longer than what was requested if the CPU is under load. This is because the OS gives each needy process a slice of CPU time (typically 20 milliseconds) before giving another timeslice to the script.

This lines up well with your 83 milliseconds being about 100.  If you follow that example link, you'll notice an example designed to make sleeps shorter than the system-hardware-based 10 or 15.6 ms limit:

```
SetBatchLines -1  ; Ensures maximum effectiveness of this method.
SleepDuration = 1  ; This can sometimes be finely adjusted (e.g. 2 is different than 3) depending on the value below.
TimePeriod = 3 ; Try 7 or 3.  See comment below.
; On a PC whose sleep duration normally rounds up to 15.6 ms, try TimePeriod=7 to allow
; somewhat shorter sleeps, and try TimePeriod=3 or less to allow the shortest possible sleeps.

DllCall("Winmm\timeBeginPeriod", uint, TimePeriod)  ; Affects all applications, not just this script's DllCall("Sleep"...), but does not affect SetTimer.
Iterations = 83
StartTime := A_TickCount

Loop %Iterations%
    DllCall("Sleep", UInt, SleepDuration)  ; Must use DllCall instead of the Sleep command.

DllCall("Winmm\timeEndPeriod", UInt, TimePeriod)  ; Should be called to restore system to normal.
MsgBox % "Sleep duration = " . (A_TickCount - StartTime) / Iterations
```

You might try an adaptation of this.  I've started:

```
SetBatchLines -1 ; This makes your script run at the fastest speed possible, thereby increasing the likelihood that you'll get exactly what time you want to get.
SleepDuration = 1 ; This and the line before it should go at the beginning of your script.

DllCall("Winmm\timeBeginPeriod", uint, TimePeriod) ; this must be before the actual sleep DllCall
Iterations = 83
StartTime := A_TickCount ; You can delete this once you know it works

Loop %Iterations%
    DllCall("Sleep", UInt, SleepDuration)  ; Must use DllCall instead of the Sleep command.

DllCall("Winmm\timeEndPeriod", UInt, TimePeriod)  ; Should be called to restore system to normal, after the middle DllCall.
MsgBox % "Sleep duration = " . (A_TickCount - StartTime) / IterationsMsgBox % "Sleep duration = " . (A_TickCount - StartTime) / Iterations ; Also delete this once you know it works
```